# How to print the current lines in Ruby one by one?

Tags: ruby, ajax, line, interrupt

I would like to print out the actual line in Ruby for demonstrative purposes to demonstrate the working of a Ruby CGI application: it would send the actual line by an AJAX call response to a webpage, and then simply wait a few seconds or for some user action.

I know there is a `__LINE__` variable, which contains the actual line number. I would like to install a signal trap, "variable watch" or other similar interrupt mechanism which is always called when `__LINE__` is changing, or if there is any dedicated interrupt which is always called and can be registered for this purpose. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller ?
With this, you scan call trace and find first related file, then extract line number with something like `/\d+(?=:in)/`